# Stripe Error - Known test bank accounts cannot be used in live mode. Payout Set up for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm trying to setup the payout process for the merchants on my site, but for some reason when I use Stripe Test bank details I get with the error of "Known test bank accounts cannot be used in live mode". I'm using the development client ID for testing obviously, so not sure why am I end up with this error. :( Any ideas would be very welcome! Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The activation form expects real information about a real business. This means that even if you're testing, you might want to create a real account with real details and that's what Stripe asks for here.

Since you're only testing the OAuth flow and don't want to activate your account you should ignore the form entirely. When testing with your Development client id `ca_XXXXX` there should be a link at the top of the form called "Skip this account form". This links lets you bypass the activation form (which would be required in production) and finish the connection with the platform.

[image]

Comment: It's pretty weird that a form accessed while in development mode (and which states that it's in development mode at the top of the form)  would create a LIVE account and want live data.  (scratching head)

Comment: I don't think it's weird, Stripe accounts have a Live and Mode test. Even though you connect your account to a *Test* platform, you might still want (or have) a real account or want to activate it later. So the activation form is for the Live part of the account and the link at the top is to skip this